# How can I change the PowerShell prompt to show just the parent directory and current directory?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I would like to shorten my PowerShell prompt so that it just shows the parent directory and the current directory. For example, if the pwd is

```
C:\Users\ndunn\OneDrive\Documents\Webucator\ClassFiles\python-basics\Demos
```

I want the prompt to be:

```
PS ..\python-basics\Demos>
```

I can get it to be just `PS ..\Demos>`  by changing the `prompt()` function in the Profile file:

1. Find location of Profile file by running `$profile` in PowerShell.
2. Open (or create and open) Profile file.
3. Change (or add) the following `prompt()` function:

---

```
function prompt
{
  $folder = "$( ( get-item $pwd ).Name )"
  "PS ..\$folder> "
}
```

---

I tried using `split()` and negative indexing, but wasn't able to get it to work.

Also, I only want to do this if the pwd is at least two levels down. If the pwd is something like C:\folder\folder, I'd like to show the default prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: For PowerShell 7, use `$PSHOME` to find the location to store the Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file. For me, that was `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7 for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following function, which should work on Windows and Unix-like platforms (in PowerShell *Core*) alike:

```
function global:prompt {
  $dirSep = [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar
  $pathComponents = $PWD.Path.Split($dirSep)
  $displayPath = if ($pathComponents.Count -le 3) {
    $PWD.Path
  } else {
    '…{0}{1}' -f $dirSep, ($pathComponents[-2,-1] -join $dirSep)
  }
  "PS {0}$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) " -f $displayPath
}
```

Note that I've chosen single character `…` ([HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS, `U+2026`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026)) to represent the omitted part of the path, because `..` could be confused with referring to the *parent* directory.

Note: The non-ASCII-range `…` character is only properly recognized if the enclosing script file - assumed to be your `$PROFILE` file - is either saved as UTF-8 *with BOM*<sup>[1]</sup> or as UTF-16LE ("Unicode").

If, for some reason, that doesn't work for you, use three distinct periods (`'...'` instead of `'…'`), though note that that will result in a longer prompt.

---

<sup>[1] The BOM is only a necessity in *Windows PowerShell*; by contrast, PowerShell *Core* assumes UTF-8 by default, so no BOM is needed.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try this (too long for a comment):

```
function prompt 
{
    $aux=$executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentFileSystemLocation.Path -Split '\\|\/'
    if ( $aux.Count -le 3 ) {
        Write-Host ("PS $($aux -join '\')>") -NoNewline # -ForegroundColor Cyan
    } else {
        Write-Host ("PS $($aux[0])\..\$($aux[-2..-1] -join '\')>") -NoNewline # -ForegroundColor Cyan
    }
    return " "
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works pretty well, but it includes the drive in the beginning. Also, I find mklement0's function clearer.

Comment: As an aside: Unless _coloring_ the prompt string is desired, you can simply _output_  the new prompt string (make it the function's "return value") - no need for `Write-Host`.

Answer (score 1):

These other replies were much more involved. Even so, here's mine. If it's greater than 30 characters, we shorten the path. Done.

```
Function Prompt {
    If ("$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)>".Length -le 30) {
        "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
    } Else {
        "PS ...\$(Split-Path -Path $executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation -Leaf)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
    } # End If.
} # End Function: Prompt.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function prompt {
    $p = split-Path -parent -path (Get-Location)
    $pl = split-Path -path $p -leaf
    $l = split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
    "$pl\$l> "
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**